# RSS feed reader web app in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, rss

I have got an idea to create a feed reader web app which would store feeds in the database and connected clients such as mobiles apps or browser can display the stored feeds. One problem in my mind is, how can I periodically fetch and parse rss feeds (say every 5 min) because i dnt want clients to initialize this process. Can anyone point me at the right direction and give me any suggestions please? 
I have looked at this Ruby library https://github.com/feedjira/feedjira which could do the job of parsing the xml.

Thanks

Comment: How can mods be marking this off-topic in a programming forum? The questioner has a clear problem to solve and is asking how to approach it.

Comment: Superfeedr [now has a Rails Engine](http://blog.superfeedr.com/consuming-rss-feeds-rails/) which makes building feed readers with Rails much simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Sidekiq](http://sidekiq.org/) and use the [Sidetiq](https://github.com/tobiassvn/sidetiq) to wake up every 5 minutes and poll feeds. It's important to keep jobs small and atomic, so you should make a single periodic job to schedule all the actual fetches.

Comment: Thanks @mahemoff those libs sound promising as for my needs. However as I am new to rails and can you tell me where in the project I would use those libs? would be in a controller ?

Comment: @adrian_88 They are actually run as separate servers, but (typically) using the same Rails code base. The Rails server is really an application server intended for taking requests and delivering responses, so it's a more robust solution to have a separate server for periodic and background tasks. There are some workarounds that will do it within the Rails server, which is less setup hassle, or you can just run a cron job or ongoing daemon. But higher-scale systems will usually use a queue-based service like Sidekiq.

Comment: Also, think about [Superfeedr](https://superfeedr.com)! It does the polling for you as well as the diffing :)